# opacity makes a neighbour element unclickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It's a fairly strange result. The code is as follows:

```
<div class="vote-buttons">
<a class="clickable vote up ">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
</a>
<span class="num">0</span>
<a class="clickable vote down " >
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
</a>
<a class="clickable vote save " 
    title=" save ">
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</a>
</div> <!--.vote-buttons-->
<div class="meta">
    title
</div>
```

what's happening is that if I set the opacity of div.meta to any value (<1), then the vote up button is not clickable. 
What I mean not clickable is that the cursor is not pointer when hovering and it has no effect when clicked.

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/flyingfoxlee/7LN6C/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding as an answer since I can't comment yet:

As @jcaron said, your `div.meta` is sitting in the same space as the vote buttons. Since the vote buttons are floating, they're removed from the normal flow, which means `div.meta` is sliding all the way up to the top of the document. However, when you set opacity on it, then it covers up the floating div.

However, @jcaron mistyped when he said `margin-right`. What you want is **`margin-left`**. A value of `30px` should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

The `div.meta` overlays the `div.vote-buttons` (as the latter has `float` set).

One option is to add a `margin-right` to your `div.meta` to get it out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd thing. I tend to prefer `rgba()` where possible, and that doesn't have the same effect, so I'd suggest that instead:

```
.meta {
    /* opacity: 0.8; */
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the same thing for me, here you're setting a black color for text in `meta` class, what if he wanted to have blue text ? Or reduce the opacity of the whole element (including background-image maybe) ?